# How do I get the size of an Iphone context

Tags: iphone, size, screen

I have;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Now I want to know the width/height of the the context (in pixels); any way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't get that information from the `CGContextRef` object, but from the surrounding `frame` object:

```
self.frame.size.width
self.frame.size.height
```

Comment: This is wrong, you should use the view's `bounds`. The view's `frame`'s size may be larger if the view is transformed.